# Apache Camel Netty4 - Unable to send response on the same socket after aggregating request chunks

Tags: java, apache, apache-camel

I have following 2 camel routes:

ROUTE 1:

```
from("netty4://tcp.....")
  .transform(constant("TEST"))
  .convertBodyTo(InputStream.class)
```

ROUTE 2:

```
from("netty4://tcp.....")
      .aggregate(header(NettyConstants.NETTY_REMOTE_ADDRESS), ...)
      .completionPredicate(....)
      .transform(constant("TEST"))
      .convertBodyTo(InputStream.class)
```

If my client app calls ROUTE 1, it sends response bytes matching "TEST". It is ok.

If my client app calls ROUTE 2, it sends request bytes in response. Why? It should work the same as ROUTE 1.

Comment: can you remove completionPredicate and check?

Comment: @GauravRai1512,  if I remove completionPredicate, application doesn't start:

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: At least one of the completions options [completionTimeout, completionInterval, completionSize, completionPredicate, completionFromBatchConsumer] must be set

Comment: @GauravRai1512, I pushed example project to github: https://github.com/lordjoker/camel